# ListView Height Based on Children

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I need to find the height of android `ListView` with custom `ListVAdapter`. Each of `ListView` items can be of varying height. I have tried the following code which I found here:

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

But it doesn't give actual height; it gives same height for all list items. Is it possible to find `ListView` height with list items of varying height?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ViewTreeObserver to archive the desired effect. Once you have Added all the childs to the list view you can call this:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = myList.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {   
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int height = myList.getMeasuredHeight();  
            int width = myList.getMeasuredWidth();

                    // Do stuff with the height and width here.
        }
    });
```

Comment: Additional, remember to remove `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()` when `onDestroyView()`. In some case it took my app crash unless I do that.

Comment: That is odd. It never happened to me. But is probably a good practice to do :) I'll implement in my apps for now on :)

Comment: I used be crashed my app when I call `getActivity().getResource()` in `onGlobalLayout()`. It throw an `illegalstateException` when I close this fragment and reopen it.